# Where to store PDFs in Tomcat

Tags: file, tomcat

I think this problem might have been asked in a similar way, but I don't get a satisfying answer.

I am trying to build a web project using *MySQL* and *Tomcat*, where a user can upload PDFs (in the future more file types) and another user can view them on their device.
In the database should only be the file paths stored and the actual files somewhere else.

Here at this point comes my problem:
Where exactly should I store the files? I've read that the best practice is to store them in the `WEB-INF`-folder, but won't they get deleted after every new deployment?
Where can I store them without the fear of losing them?

Maybe some of you have a thread, where this topic has already been discussed, otherwise I would appreciate your help under this one.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

- You are correct. If you save the PDF in the WEB-INF-folder, it will be removed with each fresh deployment. Another difficulty occurs when files are stored in the WEB-INF-folder, such as security concerns and scalability limitations.
- A better solution would be to save uploaded files in a location other than the application's deployment directory. A dedicated file system directory, a network-shared storage system, or a cloud storage service could all be used.

1. Dedicated File System Directory
2. Network-Shared Storage
3. Cloud Storage Service

- I believe my response is beneficial to you. Thanks.

Comment: How should the file path then look like? Probably not C:\\...

Comment: I think this is depend upon which type of storage method are you using. If you are using dedicated file system directory then the path will look like "/path/to/uploads/filename.pdf" and if you are using network-shared storage system then the path look like \\server\share\uploads\filename.pdf and if you are using cloud storage service then the path is s3://bucket-name/uploads/filename.pdf. The important thing is to choose a file path that is consistent, descriptive, and accessible to the application server.